# Power BI Matrix doesn't respect month order

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

**SCENARIO:** I created a Power BI Matrix.

As soon as I add the date as columns the data are split in 2022 and 2023.

But I want to see the data by month so I remove the Year and the Quarter and I only keep month.

In this case, based on the selection I have:

- **2022:** September, October, November, December
- **2023:** January, February, March

Which is good.

**PROBLEM:** If I select both years I can see all the month but they are not in the right order:

[image]

They should be in this order:

September 2022, October 2022, November 2022, December 2022, January 2023, February 2023, March 2023

I see why they do this: probably because I have removed the year.

So how can I show the month as column title and respecting the yearly order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing the year, click the button below so you can see everything in a nice format and correctly ordered.

[image]